# Fill combobox with combined data from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, combobox

I have an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfToolClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ToolClass>
    <ToolID>1</ToolID>
    <ToolName>Multiflute Endmill</ToolName>
    <ToolDia>8</ToolDia>
    <ToolTooth>4</ToolTooth>
    <ToolApmxs>32</ToolApmxs>
    <ToolCuttingSpeed>150</ToolCuttingSpeed>
    <ToolFeedPerTooth>0.04</ToolFeedPerTooth>
    <ToolAe>8</ToolAe>
    <ToolAp>4</ToolAp>
    <ToolManufacturer>SECO</ToolManufacturer>
    <ToolSerial>DKFLJDSKJ</ToolSerial>
  </ToolClass>
  <ToolClass>
    <ToolID>2</ToolID>
    <ToolName>Multiflute Endmill</ToolName>
    <ToolDia>4</ToolDia>
    <ToolTooth>4</ToolTooth>
    <ToolApmxs>25</ToolApmxs>
    <ToolCuttingSpeed>235</ToolCuttingSpeed>
    <ToolFeedPerTooth>0.03</ToolFeedPerTooth>
    <ToolAe>4</ToolAe>
    <ToolAp>0.4</ToolAp>
    <ToolManufacturer>SECO</ToolManufacturer>
    <ToolSerial>DJFKLSL</ToolSerial>
  </ToolClass>
</ArrayOfToolClass>
```

I would like to fill data to combobox:

```
displaymember= <TooDia>"x"<ToolApmxs>" mm - "<ToolName>;
valuemember=<ToolID>;
```

I tried with this code:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(@"data\tools.xml");
var toolist = xmlDocument.Descendants("ToolClass");
```

But how can I combine the data to the specified format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var toolist = xmlDocument.Descendants("ToolClass")
    .Select(tc => new
    {
        Display = tc.Element("ToolDia").Value + " x " + tc.Element("ToolApmxs").Value + " mm - " + tc.Element("ToolName").Value,
        Value = tc.Element("ToolID").Value
    })
    .ToList();

comboBox.DisplayMember = "Display";
comboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
comboBox.DataSource = toolist;
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great!

Answer (score 0):

So you can use something like this to get the inner text of the first member:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(@"data\tools.xml");

var tooList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("ToolClass").Item(0).InnerText;
```